# ftp_put giving error The parameter is incorrect wen trying to process

Tags: php, ftp, copy

I have the below syntax where I am trying to move a file in my current local server directory onto an FTP server.

```
$source = $csv_filename;
$target = fopen("/LocExports/test.csv", "w");

$conn = ftp_connect("ftp.server.co.za") or die("Could not connect");
ftp_login($conn,"username","password");

$upload = ftp_put($conn, $target,$source,FTP_ASCII);
if (!$upload) { echo 'FTP upload failed!'; }
```

This fails with error `The parameter is incorrect`

`$csv_filename` is the name of the file on my local server. it is in the same folder as the php file.

my destination is effectively:
`http://www.server.co.za/kisv2/xmltest/`

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks as always,

**UPDATE**

As per alex's advice, here is updated syntax:

```
$csv_filename = 'export-2013-06-13 15:19:48.csv';
$source = $csv_filename;  //this is a file in the same directory as my php file. full path is... http://www.server.co.za/kisv2/xmltest/export-2013-06-13 15:19:48.csv
$target = '/LocExports/'.$csv_filename; //full path is... ftp://ftp.hulamin.co.za/LocExports/

$conn = ftp_connect("ftp.server.co.za") or die("Could not connect");
ftp_login($conn, "username", "password");

$upload = ftp_put($conn, $target, $source, FTP_ASCII);
if (!$upload) { echo 'FTP upload failed!'; }
```

Comment: You are passing a file handle as the second parameter but ftp_put expects a remote filename `ftp_put($conn, REMOTE_FILE, LOCAL_FILE, FTP_ASCII);`

Comment: Thanks, can you elaborate? what is a file handle? Thanks Alex.

Comment: `$target = fopen(...)` results in a file handle assigned to $target, but that doesn't make any sense to pass that as the REMOTE_FILE to ftp_put. I'll post an answer in a second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the `fopen()` like this:

```php
$csv_filename = 'test.csv';
$source = '/local/path/to/'.$csv_filename; 
$target = '/LocExports/'.$csv_filename;

$conn = ftp_connect("ftp.server.co.za") or die("Could not connect");
ftp_login($conn, "username", "password");

$upload = ftp_put($conn, $target, $source, FTP_ASCII);
if (!$upload) { echo 'FTP upload failed!'; }
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, I have updated my syntax in the question, still getting error though. error is:

Comment: `Warning: ftp_put() [function.ftp-put]: The parameter is incorrect`

Comment: What is in `$csv_filename` ? (I want the full and exact value)

Comment: Hi Alex. you might be onto something as the filename had spaces(datetime value). I have now changed it to `exportname.csv`. when this uploads, the file appears on ftp but is blank. error is now `Warning: ftp_put() [function.ftp-put]: Opening ASCII mode data connection` Thanks

Comment: Add `ftp_pasv($conn, true);` after your `ftp_login()`

Comment: Accept this answer because it fixed your fopen() path problems, and let's continue with the warning message in your other question.

Comment: Thanks Alex. think the filename having spaces was adding to the issues too. Accepted and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Just to be clear, as it's rather buried in comments on another answer:

`"The parameter is incorrect"` is caused by an invalid destination filename.  Make sure you don't have any invalid characters (slash, colon, etc...) in your filename.

Comment: In my case destination filename contained colon (":") and that caused an issue on Windows Server where ftp was configured